# Tag not found in repository docker.io/minio

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

We have been using locked version of the Minio image (`RELEASE.2016-10-07T01-16-39Z`), but now it seems to have been removed.

I'm getting this from Docker:

```
Pulling minio (minio/minio:RELEASE.2016-10-07T01-16-39Z)...
Pulling repository docker.io/minio/minio
ERROR: Tag RELEASE.2016-10-07T01-16-39Z not found in repository docker.io/minio/minio
```

I'm finding Docker hub hard to navigate. Where can I find a list of available versioned images, or a mirror to my exact image?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the available tags for `minio/minio` on that repository's [tag page](https://hub.docker.com/r/minio/minio/tags/).

If you have the image you want already downloaded on any of your systems, you can push it to Docker Hub yourself, then pull it onto your other systems. This has the benefit that you can control whether you delete that image (it's your account, not someone else's).

You can also use a private registry, if you want, which would prevent Docker from deleting the image from Docker Hub against your will for some reason. But that is extra work you may not wish to do (you would have to host the registry yourself, set it up, maintain it...)

Answer (score 1):

We removed the docker version due to incompatibilities, from the recent releases it won't happen.

Comment: Seems like this happened again recently to version `RELEASE.2021-05-27T22-06-31Z`. Still got it locally from fetching a few days ago, now it's gone on docker hub.

Comment: These are all the quarantined images - RELEASE.2021-05-11T23-27-41Z
RELEASE.2021-05-16T05-32-34Z
RELEASE.2021-05-18T00-53-28Z
RELEASE.2021-05-20T22-31-44Z
RELEASE.2021-05-22T02-34-39Z
RELEASE.2021-05-26T00-22-46Z
RELEASE.2021-05-27T22-06-31Z